# Embed pdf chrome not always working

Tags: jquery, css, google-chrome, pdf, embed

I have object/embed pdf files in my html that work fine in many browsers. Even at Chrome it loads correctly, but when I hide it to show another app tool, when I come to show the pdf again, it doesn't appear again. No reloading, no ajax, just show/hide. Then, when I go to console and change the css display attribute of the parent div (to table, ie), the pdf shows up, but the same workarround do not work dinamically in the script. Any tip?

Comment: z-index possibly?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the anwser until now was to create two nested setTimeouts functions. In the first one I hide the container, in the second one I show it up again. Than it works... with a small blink, but it's there.